# Image transition at a certain interval of time in windows phone 8 C# app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am a beginner developing a windows phone 8  C# app.

In the app i am playing a song which and I have some images to show. in app. I want to show the images in a certain interval of  time along with the song. that is if the song played for 1 minute, the image will change to the next image in a transition..and at the 2 minute of song playing another image will load And so on..

Can any one help on this how to change the image on a particular interval of time by transitions. with any example.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Extending @Toni's answer

Assuming

1. You already created storyboard and bind your start of animation with
   [property change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj733159%28v=vs.105%29.aspx),
2. Have list of source of images for Property Changed Trigger

then use below function extension for Image:

```
public static async Task ChangeSourceAfter(this Image imageToAnimate, double sec, ImageSource src)
{
 await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec));

 //Now change image source, also trigger animation if PropertyChangedTrigger used
 imageToAnimate.Source = src;

}
```

Usage:

```
ImageToAnimate.ChangeSourceAfter(60, newSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

To wait for the specified time to pass, you can use `Task.Delay`:

```
async Task Foo()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    // now after 60 seconds this piece of code will happen
}
```

Don't forget that you must monitor for cancellation when user navigates away or closes the application.

If you are using `Storyboard`s, you can specify that they start at the later time.

Comment: it says me that time span not exists in current context

Comment: I am sorry, it is `TimeSpan` with capital s. You should be familiar with that class.

Comment: I tried that TimeSpan as you specified, but still shows me the error.. are you having sny code exaamples .. if please refer it Thank you